# Ruby: skips over a gets value

Tags: ruby, file, sorting, object

I have a file check and sort script. Now I wanted the user to be to choose how he/she wishes to have the final output sorted. Sadly Ruby seems to ignore the gets command. If I comment out the entire section the script finishes just fine. Please ignore the def readout. I never finished that one....

So my question is: Why does Ruby skip over the gets command.

```
class Product
  attr_reader :id, :name, :price, :stock
  def initialize(id,name,price,stock)
    @id = id
    @name=name
    @price=price
    @stock=stock
  end
  def readout
    self.each do |product|
      print product.id
      print "|"
      print product.name
      print "|"
      print product.price
      print "|"
      print product.stock
      puts ""
    end
  end
end

products = []
newproducts= []

if ARGV[0] != nil
  if File.exist?(ARGV[0])
    File.open(ARGV[0] , "r") do |f|
      f.each_line do |line|
        products << line
      end
    end
    products.each do |product|
      data = product.split(",")
      newproducts.push(Product.new(data[0].strip, data[1].strip, data[2].strip.to_i, data[3].strip.to_i))
    end

    puts "What to sort by?"
    question = gets.strip
    if question == "name"
      newproducts.sort! {|a,b| b.name <=> a.name}
    elsif question == "price"
      newproducts.sort! {|a,b| b.price <=> a.price}
    elsif question =="id"
      newproducts.sort! {|a,b| b.id <=> a.id}
    elsif question == "stock"
      newproducts.sort! {|a,b| b.stock <=> a.stock}
    else
      puts "Wrong Answer."
    end

    #End of File Check
  else
    puts "File #{ARGV[0]} does not exist."
  end

  if ARGV[1] != nil
    File.open(ARGV[1], "w") do |f|
      newproducts.each do |product|
        puts "Added #{product.name} to the file."
        data = {product.id, product.name, product.price, product.stock}
        f.puts(data)
      end
    end
    #End of ARGV check.
  else
    puts "No output file assigned."
  end

  #End of master ARGV check.
else
  puts "No command given."
end
```

Comment: For the future: It is generally a good idea to reduce your non-working code to an example which is as short as possible, but when run still exhibits the same error as the original. This greatly increases the chance of someone being able (or willing) to spot the mistake in a timely manner.

Comment: Also, when you think a core routine in a language isn't working right, and that language has been around a while, odds are really good the problem isn't in the core routine, it's in your code. At that point it's a great idea to step back, go read the documents very closely without looking at your code, then 30 minutes later look at your code again. Sometimes the problem will jump out at you. I've had coworkers tell me they'd found bugs in C's input routines before, swearing up and down it was in the compiler. Sure enough, it was their code. :-)

Comment: I expected that it would be in my code. I'm still not sure where to find a good guide to learning ruby. I had been mulling over this code for ages now and asked my classmates as well. No one could come up with an answer as to why it wasn't responding. Some people suggested that it might be NetBeans on OSX. 
Thank you so much for your help. 
@sepp2k: I'm not sure how much of that could've been cut down, I wasn't sure if my file checks weren't interfering somehow.

Comment: @Fallion: If you're not sure whether a certain piece of code causes or interacts with the problem, remove it and see whether anything changes. In addition to making the code shorter to post it here, that gives you valuable information about where the problem is located.

Comment: As for a good guide, there are lots of books available, either online or for purchase. Personally I buy the hard copy of ones I want to read cover to cover, and the ebook version of ones I want as reference or for fast searching. Check [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=ruby&x=0&y=0#/ref=sr_kk_3?rh=i%3Astripbooks%2Ck%3Aruby+programming&keywords=ruby+programming&ie=UTF8&qid=1290709383) and [Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) and [Ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/)

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow has a [number of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+books) looking for Ruby books.

Comment: @Greg: That principle is sometimes called "Select isn't broken".

Comment: @Andrew Grimm that's when I want to reach over and slap a coworker's head. It was funny that the last one who did that came up about a year later and basically apologized for acting like a noob.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Kernel#gets` method reads from `ARGF` not `$stdin`. This means that if command line arguments were given (or more accurately if `ARGV` is not empty) it reads from the files in ARGV. Only otherwise does it read from stdin.

To always read from stdin, use `$stdin.gets` instead of `gets`.

Comment: Thanks so much. It works now. I didn't know that's how Ruby handled ARGV vs stdin

Comment: @Fallion: Most people don't until it bites them. It's probably one of the most common ruby pitfalls.